# Python: tuple values into separate df columns?

Tags: python, dictionary

Following is the output of my dictionary output:

```
{'20140201':(2.8,a),'20140202':(3.4,b),'20140203':(5.4,c)}
```

I want to convert this dictionary output to a dataframe containing three columns, lets call it 'x','y','z'. Column x should have datevalues, y should have numerical value of tuple and z should have class value of the tuple. Is there any good way to do so. I know I can take individual dictionary values and keys and keep on adding to the existing dataframe. I am looking for a code along the lines:

```
output_dataframe=pd.DataFrame(input_goals.items(),columns=['date_id','target_goal_value','target_goal_type'])
```

Currently this code is giving me an error of having 2 values for 3 columns specified....

Comment: Can you post the expected output of your `DataFrame` command given the  above dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `input_goals.items()` you should transform it in a list of tuple as in these lines:

```
listTup = [(x, y, z) for x, (y, z) in input_goals.items()] 
output_dataframe=pd.DataFrame(listTup, columns=['date_id','target_goal_value','target_goal_type'])
```

Comment: +1: Would be good to note that this prints the above data from the end first. A `.reverse()` on the your `listTup` is an option to show it in the original order, ie. beginning with `20140201`.